# What is or is there a verb (and adjective) for the noun 'confluence'?

Tags: verbs, nouns, verbing

I would like to know if there is a verb for ***confluence***. I have looked through most of the established dictionaries as well as on the internet.

If there is no verb (and possibly no adjective, too), would you verbify the noun to ***to confluence*** as Americans tend to do with many nouns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a direct verb equivalent, but there's a very similar option. [*Confluence* comes from](https://www.etymonline.com/word/confluence) Latin origins meaning "flow together." There's no verb like "to conflue." But there is *converge*, [which comes from](https://www.etymonline.com/word/converge) Latin for "turn/bend/lean together." The modern meanings of [confluence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confluence) and [convergence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convergence) are near identical—both meaning multiple things coming together—so *converge* can serve as a stand-in for the missing "conflue!"

(Oh, and adjectives—yes, there is *converging*, which is good because *confluing* is just *confusing*!)

Comment: I remember my geography teacher saying that the Rhône - Saône confluence is where those rivers meet, so I would use 'meeting'.

Comment: Also, note: *confluence* is very much a word to choose when talking about actual rivers. To use it metaphorically of other things, note that the definition linked above describes it as "somewhat formal." If you're looking to recast a sentence like "We stand at the confluence of tradition and innovation," you might just tone down the poeticism and say "We're at the place that tradition and innovation converge."

Comment: Or meet........?

Comment: Join and meet come straight from the map, and merge is also good if you want to emphasise the mixing.